# Cannot find the post method when doing a httpcallout through flows to convert an opportunity to salesagreement

Tags: rest, salesforce, salesforce-flow

In Salesforce, I am trying to convert an opportunity to sales agreement through `HTTPCallOut` Action using flows and it does not give me an option to select the POST method, it only has the GET method.

I created a legacy Named credential with the URL - https://xxx-c1.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/connect/manufacturing/sales-agreements.

Any inputs in this regard would be appreciated.

1. The manufacturing cloud developer guide says POST method is supported - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mfg_api_devguide.meta/mfg_api_devguide/connect_resources_sales_agreement.htm
2. I tried to edit the external service created by the flow with the httpcallout action and it doesn't allow to edit